# Can I play Star Trek: Birth of the Federation any more?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

I had a brief addiction to Star Trek: Birth of the Federation back in the day. I don’t have the CD any more.

Is it available anywhere? If so, does it run on Windows XP?

Comment: This was a great game, thanks for the blast from the past!

Comment: @John: wasn’t it just? It deserved a great sequel I always thought.

Comment: Note that there is apparently still [a modding community for the game](http://www.armadafleetcommand.com/botf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be still available from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000K4DW) (albeit very expensive if you want it new.)

Seeing it is a DirectX 6 game, I assume it still runs on Windows XP (however, it probably won't run on the 64-bit version)

Comment: Good lord, there it is.

Comment: If you're also using Linux, there's a very good chance [that it will work well with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7308).

Answer (score 6):

It even runs on Win7, 64bit. At least, it works on my machine.

Comment: (I’ve also just found the CD, so I might have to crank this up again soon.)